# C# error when a loop is inside a timer1_Tick function

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I don't know much about threading. I simply have a timer1 in the UI, when I put this while loop inside the timer1_Tick function which is 100 intervals:

```
count = port.BytesToRead;
while (count > 0)
{
  // get the new byte:
  char inchar = (char)port.ReadChar();
  // add it to the inputstring:
  inputString += inchar;
  // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
  // so the main loop can do something about it:
  if (inchar == '\n')
  {
     stringComplete = true;
  }
}
```

The program stop responding for any UI input.I know that the problem is about threading and UI thread but I have few knowledge in threading as I said. 
 So what is the solution for such a problem

Comment: Is your timer enabled?

Comment: @imsome1 yes it is

Comment: Is it responding for first request from UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not decrementing your `count` variable so `while(count > 0)` never exits.

Comment: @sabsab Yes, but you are setting the value before the loop and never change the value within the loop. Therefore once it has been set to a value > 0 it will forever be > 0 in the loop.